# How do I open local image file, encode it, and post via URI? (posting via Tumblr API)

Tags: ruby, image, url, encoding, tumblr

I'm trying to read local image file, properly encode it and post to Tumbrl. According to the  [Tumblr API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting)  I can pass a parameter `data` which is `Array (URL-encoded binary contents) Limit: 5 MB`

I've tested my code with `http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/#{BLOG}/info` request. It is working. But I can't post a photo. Here is my code:

```
require 'oauth'
require 'oauth/consumer'
require 'open-uri'
require 'active_support'

CONSUMER = 'foo'
SECRET = 'foo'
TOKEN = 'foo'
TOKEN_SECRET = 'foo'
BLOG = 'foo'

consumer=OAuth::Consumer.new(CONSUMER, SECRET, {:site=>"http://tumblr.com"})
access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new(consumer, TOKEN, TOKEN_SECRET)

# Here I tried one of two lines:
# data = Base64.encode64(IO.binread('./resized')) #first try
data = URI::encode(IO.binread('./resized')) #second try

# response = access_token.get "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/#{BLOG}/info?api_key=#{CONSUMER}"
# puts response
response=access_token.post "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/#{BLOG}/post?api_key=#{CONSUMER}&type=photo&data=#{data}&link=http://ya.ru&"
puts response
```

1st try:

```
% ruby ./w_oauth.rb 
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:176:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/foo/post?api_key=foo&type=photo&data=/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD//gA7Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4w (URI::InvalidURIError)
ICh1c2luZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2NjIpLCBxdWFsaXR5ID0gODAK/9sAQwAGBAUG
BQQGBgUGBwcGCAoQCgoJCQoUDg8MEBcUGBgXFBYWGh0lHxobIxwWFiAsICMm
(!!!long piece of image data skipped!!!)
FI/16HfTbyHPWurqdE+TGH4wx2js5SKQb+6b4bIj3aurqCrEtcXrf/4yf/dS
DLet/wCzEB6sa6uoomxJN2eaQj5mkYuerQj611dQM7Fx/wDLF/8AbXV1dTA/
/9k=
&link=http://ya.ru&
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:211:in `parse'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:747:in `parse'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/tokens/access_token.rb:7:in `request'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/tokens/access_token.rb:47:in `post'
    from ./w_oauth.rb:23:in `<main>'
```

2nd try:

```
% ruby ./w_oauth.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/helper.rb:14:in `force_encoding': can't modify frozen String (RuntimeError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/helper.rb:14:in `rescue in escape'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/helper.rb:12:in `escape'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/helper.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in normalize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/helper.rb:42:in `collect'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/helper.rb:42:in `block in normalize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/helper.rb:37:in `map'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/helper.rb:37:in `normalize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/request_proxy/base.rb:98:in `normalized_parameters'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/request_proxy/base.rb:113:in `signature_base_string'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/signature/base.rb:77:in `signature_base_string'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/signature/hmac/base.rb:12:in `digest'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/signature/base.rb:65:in `signature'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/signature.rb:23:in `sign'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/client/helper.rb:45:in `signature'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/client/helper.rb:75:in `header'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/client/net_http.rb:91:in `set_oauth_header'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/client/net_http.rb:30:in `oauth!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:224:in `sign!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:188:in `create_signed_request'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:159:in `request'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/tokens/consumer_token.rb:25:in `request'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/tokens/access_token.rb:12:in `request'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth-0.4.6/lib/oauth/tokens/access_token.rb:47:in `post'
    from ./w_oauth.rb:23:in `<main>'
```

UPD: `./resized` is a proper JPEG file:

```
% file ./resized
./resized: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, comment: "CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 80"
```

Answer (score 0):

URI encoding is not enough. You also need to encode: `, / ? : @ & = + $ #`.

Try:

```ruby
URI.escape(IO.binread('./resized'), Regexp.new("[^#{URI::PATTERN::UNRESERVED}]"))
```